# Minitoc not showing at the start of a chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I have included the command `\usepackage{minitoc}` in preamble and amended the code

```
\AtBeginDocument{
\dominitoc
\dominilof
\dominilot
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
}
```

After `\begin{document}` I then have

```
\tableofcontents % Prints the main table of contents
\bigskip
\mbox{Word count: \wordcount words} % Add word count at end of contents table

\listoffigures % Prints the list of figures
\listoftables % Prints the list of tables
```

And then within the subfile `Chapter1.tex` I have the format:

```
% Chapter 1
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction} % Main chapter title
\label{Chap1:Intro} % Change X to a consecutive number; for referencing this chapter elsewhere, use \ref{ChapterX}
\minitoc

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{The Steam Turbine}
```

When compiling the document though no minitoc shows at the start of Chap.1. 
Why is this? Is minitoc compatible with `subfile`?

Comment: Anyone got ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My file contained several chapters that were not actual chapters i.e. list of figures, list of tables, abstract.

To account for these it was necessary to include the command `\mtcaddchapter`. It must be included for the number of additional chapters so in the case above this would be three commands of `mtcaddchapter`. It should be added after the `\tableofcontents` command.